# Ansible:kubernetes install using vagrant, error: "server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, vagrant, virtualbox

Trying to install kubernetes on virtualbox using ansible:

in master-playbook.yml

```
  - name: Install comodo cert
    copy: src=BCPSG.pem dest=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

  - name: Update cert index
    shell: /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates

  - name: Adding apt repository for Kubernetes
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/  kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
      filename: kubernetes.list
      validate_certs: False
```

now, Vagrantfile calls the playbook:

```
config.vm.define "k8s-master" do |master|
    master.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
    master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
    master.vm.hostname = "k8s-master"
    master.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "kubernetes-setup/master-playbook.yml"
    end
end
```

but i am getting error:

> ```
> TASK [Adding apt repository for Kubernetes] ************************************
> fatal: [k8s-master]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n",
> ```
>
> "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File
>   \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555907987.70663-229510485563848/AnsiballZ_apt_repository.py\",
>   line 113, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File
>   \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555907987.70663-229510485563848/AnsiballZ_apt_repository.py\",
>   line 105, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod,
>   temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File
>   \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555907987.70663-229510485563848/AnsiballZ_apt_repository.py\",
>   line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('**main**', mod,
>   module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_apt_repository_payload_GXYAmU/**main**.py\", line 550,
>   in \r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_apt_repository_payload_GXYAmU/**main**.py\", line 542,
>   in main\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py\",
>   line 487, in update\r\n    raise
>   FetchFailedException(e)\r\napt.cache.FetchFailedException: W:The
>   repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists
>   kubernetes-xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from
>   such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially
>   dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation
>   and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch
>   https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/dists/kubernetes-xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   server certificate verification failed. CAfile:
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none, E:Some index files
>   failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used
>   instead.\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact
>   error", "rc": 1}

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100800/kubernetes-installation-failing-ubuntu-16-04 -- seems similar to the above. Also there is another link in the comments of the question

Comment: `    copy: src=BCPSG.pem dest=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is almost certainly an **absolutely terrible** idea, since that file (as its plural name implies) is  a concatenation of a lot of certificates; the correctly way is to download any new certificate into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and then call [`update-ca-certificates`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html)

Answer (score 1):

As is described in [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl), you must first add the GPG signing key with `apt-key` or the ansible module [`apt_key:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/apt_key_module.html#apt-key-module)

Similarly listed on that page, the correct apt repo is `deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main`

So yes, while you entirely borked your CA chain of trust with the first command, I suspect you would have subsequently encountered untrusted package signatures with the next steps since you did not teach apt apt the kubernetes package signing key.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command below and try again:

# git config --global http.sslverify false